# How to change key from json or an anonymous object in c#

Tags: c#, json, linq

I need help to change the key value after applying condition, here is my code snippet ,

> {"gstin":"27GSPMH0411G1Z1","fp":"012018","gt":0,"cur_gt":0,**"cdnur"**:[{"sply_ty":"INTER","diff_percent":0.0,"rt":45.0,"typ":"OE","etin":"","pos":"24","txval":-13000.0,"iamt":-10000.0,"csamt":0.0}]}

As in above json string i want to override or change or update the key "cdnur" (bold) to something else using linq.

Comment: If you have the object as a string (strObject), just replace the key: `strObject.Replace("cdnur", "newValue");`

Comment: `here is my code snippet` No it not your code snippet, it is the json you get somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove *cdnur* and then add the value with a different name...

```
var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(JSON);
var cdnur = jsonObj["cdnur"];
jsonObj.Remove("cdnur");
jsonObj.Add(new JProperty("NEW-NAME",cdnur));
```

*PS: using [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)*